# How to assign a String array as a column to a 2d String array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception, assign

i ran into a problem in 2d arrays(string datatype) in java. i have 
    another array named arr and i want to input names in a single string array a 
    and copy those names to the columns of row 0 of the 2d array. please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Strings
{
  public static void main(String[] args)// main function
   {
    String qwert[][]=new String[5][];
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter no of columns");
    String arr[]= new String[5];
    int t=reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("now arr input");
    for(int k=0;k<t;k++)
        arr[k]=reader.next();
        for(int j=0;j<t;j++)
        {
            qwert[0][j]=arr[j];
        }
        for(int b=0;b<t;b++)
            System.out.println(qwert[0][b]);
   }//main function ends
}//class ends
```

Comment: what the problem, do you get any error or something

Answer (score 1):

`String qwert[][] = new String[5][];` creates an array of 5 array which all are null thus `quert[0] = null`. When you try to assing in your `for`, `qwert[0][j] = arr[j]`, `qwert[0]` is null so you will get a `NullPointerException`. You need to initialize `qwert[i]` before you use it.

```
// you need to initialize qwert[0]
qwert[0] = new String[t];
for(int j = 0; j < t; j++)
{
    qwert[0][j] = arr[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code provided below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Strings
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)// main function
       {
        String qwert[][]=new String[5][];
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter no of columns");
        String arr[]= new String[5];
        int t=reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("now arr input");
        qwert[0] = new String[t];
        for(int k=0;k<t;k++)
            arr[k]=reader.next();
            for(int j=0;j<t;j++)
            {
                qwert[0][j]=arr[j];
            }
            for(int b=0;b<t;b++)
                System.out.println(qwert[0][b]);
       }//main function ends
    }//class ends
```

You need to initialize the second dimension of **qwert** before using it,
otherwise it will generate NullPointerException on its use. The line **qwert[0] = new String[t];** initialize the array so that it can be used for further value assignment.

Comment: Why? What does this code demonstrate? Simply dumping code with no explanation did not make a good answer.